# get an exception about function that does not exist event when i see it on the code

Tags: javascript

this is example of code that i wrote - and for some reason i get an exception about missing function event when i clearly see the function in the code

- the myClass is singleton .. but i don't see any problem here that can cause this

```js
class myClass {
  constructor() {
    this._data = [];
  }

  add(item) {
    this._data.push(item);
  }

  get(id) {
    return this._data.find(d => d.id === id);
  }

  func1() {
    // ...
  }

  func2() {
    // ...
  }

  locateItem(id) {
    var tmp1 = get(id); // i get here exception => the function 'get' does not exist
    //var tmp2 = this.get(id); // same exception as in last line
  }
}

const instance = new myClass();
export default instance;
```

calling this function ( as its singleton )

```
         var tmp = instance.locateItem(100);
```

Comment: How are you calling `locateItem`?

Comment: @ASDFGerte:: the breackpoint on the locateItem is stop - so the call the locateItem is ok

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. I am assuming you are not calling `locateItem` in proper context but can't be sure as you do not show how you call it. As an example: `let x = instance.locateItem; x();` would produce your behavior.

Comment: @ASDFGerte :: the 'myClass' is singleton. i calling the method locateItem     

var tmp = instance.locateItem(100);

The context is ok => i calling other method in same way with no problem

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Works for me on Node 10.0.0 - the only thing i did was not use babel, ecma module flags or the likes, so i replaced `export default` with `module.exports = `.

Comment: If you get this error with this too, your code differs from the one in the question

Comment: @baao .. same code .. copy paste from my visual studio code .. same

Comment: Maybe you forgot to comment `var tmp1 = get(id);` when trying `var tmp2 = this.get(id);`? By the way, as has been noted, the one without `this` prefixed should never work so you don't need to keep that in.

Comment: @ASDFGerte ::: this is not my first code that i writing. i know how to write code. i did not forgot to comment. i wrote this code here because i never saw this kind of problem before.

Comment: What is `this` at the start of the related `locateItem` call?

Answer (score 1):

That’s because `get` is not a function, `this.get()` is one though.

You need to use `this` to access class members and methods from within a class

Comment: so how to call the function from same class function ?

Comment: From the question: "//var tmp2 = this.get(id); // same exception as in last line"

Comment: as i wrote ... i already try to use 'this' and no other result

Comment: Exactly as I wrote. this.get(id)

Comment: Ah, I've been on mobile and didn't see that. Please post your actual code - it would work with this for above class: https://jsfiddle.net/1zx6246y/